# Should I vote to close the question with the accepted answer or the question that has more info?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

A user asked two similar questions in quick succession:

1. [Are method declarations (not definitions) possible in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107329/are-method-declarations-not-definitions-possible-in-javascript)
2. [Is it possible to foward declare a function or method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107189/is-it-possible-to-foward-declare-a-function-or-method-in-javascript)

The first one has an accepted answer already but the second one has better answers (IMO). Are there any guidelines I should use to make decisions in situations like this? I'm currently thinking about voting to close the first one.

Answer (score 1):

My general rule of thumb is to dup the later, unless the first has no answers or very poor answers. For this specific situation, I would still probably suggest marking [Are method declarations (not definitions) possible in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107329/are-method-declarations-not-definitions-possible-in-javascript) as a duplicate of [Is it possible to foward declare a function or method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107189/is-it-possible-to-foward-declare-a-function-or-method-in-javascript), especially since the question itself in [Is it possible to foward declare a function or method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107189/is-it-possible-to-foward-declare-a-function-or-method-in-javascript) appears to be of slightly higher quality.  Then comment on the answer in [Are method declarations (not definitions) possible in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107329/are-method-declarations-not-definitions-possible-in-javascript) telling him to post his answer to [Is it possible to foward declare a function or method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107189/is-it-possible-to-foward-declare-a-function-or-method-in-javascript).